# Sitecore Powershell Extension - Is there any way to "tag" media files and download media files with particular tag?

Tags: powershell-extensions

As you can see from the title I need to make a script to get all of the `media files` from particular path (`sitecore/content/Media Library` for example) and to download those media files that are matching particular **set of tags**, or a **simple tag**.

In addition to that, how to actually tag the media files items? It does not have to be automatically done, just manual tagging, let's say it like that

If you have any tips on how to do it, or reference to similar script I would gladly appreciate it. Thank you in advance everybody!

Comment: What query do you have so far to find the media items?

Comment: @MichaelWest `$mediaItems = Get-ChildItem -Path master: -ID $mediaRootItem.ID -Recurse` the `$mediaRootItem.ID` is something that can be selected with Powershell Report, if you understand what I am saying by that (basically the folder). I know how to select media items, but don't know how to select media items with tag

Comment: I would start here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/ and check out the report examples included with SPE. Each one shows how to filter results.

Comment: @MichaelWest I have managed to finish part of finding the media items with specific tag. Do you know how to download images from Powershell Extension?

Comment: @Samke11 https://mostlysitecore.wordpress.com/2021/03/25/download-files-from-media-library-using-sitecore-powershell-extension/